# Restore subscriber from subscriber's backup

Tags: sql-server, replication

We have currently pull transaction replication with 1 publisher, 1 distributor and several subscribers. The replication is for several tables only.
I want to create new subscriber and this time restore it from backup. All the process and configuration is pretty simple, but I wanted to check if the following will work:

1. backup the publisher
2. backup one of the subscriber (right after no.1).
3. copy subscribers backup (which is much lighter) to the future subscriber and restore
4. define the new subscriber.

From my tests it is picking data and works ok, but I didn't test it heavily yet.
Is this practical?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have mentioned should be fine. Just remember to script out the  replication before doing this as a backup.

1. Script out the replication.
2. Take the database backup for Publisher.
3. Backup one of the subscriber (right after no.1).
4. Copy subscribers backup (which is much lighter) to the future subscriber and restore
5. Configure the new subscription accordingly.